# What is a good website to find sys-admins?

Tags: website

Where can I find a company that provides sys-admin/server management on-demand? I don't mean those consulting/tech companies that wants to get you under a contract, but the ones that could just accept the task and bill you by the hour.

Or a web site where you can post a job and get instant responses? I don't mean Odesk kind but more specific to good sys-admins.

My problem is that you can't hire someone and expect him to be a pro about every aspect of Linux, so sometimes we need an LDAP guy, sometimes we need Plesk person etc.

I'd be glad if you just post the websites you know, this may be helpful to everyone.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel obliged to say jobs.serverfault.com

I would recommend that you find a very good consultant and just task them with projects from time to time.  If you always try to find "an expert" on "a website", you're going to find a lot of people who claim to be experts are really quite lackluster once past the interview process.

When you want a company to just randomly give you an expert, you're going to do a lot of repeat work where they familiarize themselves with how you currently have your systems setup and what procedures you follow.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I don't know of a SysAdmin equivalent to RentACoder.com (which might be a good thing...) there are other freelancer sites out there that you might want to look into. For instance, elance.com and guru.com. A targeted Google search for "[Rent a SysAdmin](http://www.google.com/search?q="rent+a+sysadmin")" comes back with highly speculative results.

You might want to read Jeff Atwood's article "[Can you really rent a coder?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001190.html)" but substitute the word "coder" with "sysadmin". I hope that doesn't sound nagging... I'm just sayin'.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember that sometimes you need this guy to have root / admin privileges and I am not sure this is the most secure way to run your business.
Better find someone - that he is good in the area you need and stick with him.
If he will need any help from other specialist he will make the further contacts, not exposing more people to your system.

Comment: Good tip. Yes, we have that guy, but he isn't good at finding others :) I hope he reads this !